# Getting all figures on a single page

Tags: align, charts

I have 6 images I would like on one page, however only 4 appear on one page and the other 2 appear on the second page. Any ideas how I can fix this? Many Thanks

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\begin{figure}[h]
 \centering
 \begin{subfigure}[h]{0.49\textwidth}
   \caption*{Figure B3}
  \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{IPL Nationality Breakdown (Full Data Set).png} 
 \end{subfigure}%
 \hfill
 \begin{subfigure}[h]{0.49\textwidth}
   \caption*{Figure B4}
  \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{IPL Nationality Breakdown (SOLD).png}
 \end{subfigure}
 \end{figure}
 \vspace{0.05cm}
 \begin{figure}[h]
 \centering
 \begin{subfigure}[h]{0.49\textwidth}
   \caption*{Figure B5}
  \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{graph1.png} 
 \end{subfigure}%
  \hfill
 \begin{subfigure}[h]{0.49\textwidth}
   \caption*{Figure B6}
  \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{graph2.png}
 \end{subfigure}
 \end{figure}
  \begin{figure}[h]
 \centering
 \begin{subfigure}{0.49\textwidth}
   \caption*{Figure B7}
  \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{Relationship ipl exp auction price.png} 
 \end{subfigure}%
 \hfill
 \begin{subfigure}[h]{0.49\textwidth}
 \caption*{Figure B8}
  \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{IPL Bowling economy auction price.png}
 \end{subfigure}
 \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output I get]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please extend your code fragment to complete small document with your figure (beginning with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See, if the following MWE gives what you like to have:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}  % in real document remove `demo` option
\usepackage{caption,subcaption}
 \captionsetup[subfigure]{skip=0.5ex}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[ht]
 \centering
 \setkeys{Gin}{width=1\textwidth}
 \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.49\textwidth}
   \caption*{Figure B3}
  \includegraphics{IPL Nationality Breakdown (Full Data Set).png}
 \end{subfigure}%
 \hfill
 \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.49\textwidth}
   \caption*{Figure B4}
  \includegraphics{IPL Nationality Breakdown (SOLD).png}
 \end{subfigure}

\bigskip
 \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.49\textwidth}
   \caption*{Figure B5}
  \includegraphics{graph1.png}
 \end{subfigure}%
  \hfill
 \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.49\textwidth}
   \caption*{Figure B6}
  \includegraphics{graph2.png}
 \end{subfigure}

\bigskip
  \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.49\textwidth}
   \caption*{Figure B7}
  \includegraphics{Relationship ipl exp auction price.png}
 \end{subfigure}%
 \hfill
 \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.49\textwidth}
 \caption*{Figure B8}
  \includegraphics{IPL Bowling economy auction price.png}
 \end{subfigure}
    \end{figure}
 \end{document}
```

*Note:* All `subfigure`s are in one `figure`:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Really Appreciated

Comment: @AaronSachdev, you are welcome. If answer solve your problem, you can (now) up-vote it as well accept it (by clicking on up pen and check mark at top left side of answer ;-)